# Giving css to session flash data in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, flash

Is there a way to set css to codeigniter session flashdata. I want to give success or error message when user is redirected from controller to view after success or error. Suppose

### In controller

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("msg", "<div class='alert alert-success'> Data successfully inserted.</div>");
redirect("contoller/method");
```

### In view

```
echo $this->session->flashdata("msg");
```

In this case I get success alert of bootstrap. But I need to make div in all `set_flashdata` and its to lengthy process. I want to know, If its possible to send third parameter to flashdata thats help to know if its error flashdata or success flash and accordingly show bootstrap success or error alert. Any help would be greatfull.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your request well, you should dedicate value to variable regarding insert process. Than you should set flashdata. Something like:

```
$insert = $this->Some_model->insert($data);
if ($insert != false) {//or any controll you could make in model method return
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'> Data successfully inserted.</div>";
} else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Error while inserting. Please try again.</div>";
}
$this->session->set_flashdata("msg", $msg);
```

Comment: This is not what I mean. I want to make flashdata message like bootstrap alert.

Comment: You should include view code pointing where you expect alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it that way... `session->set_flashdata` is cleared every time you use a `redirect()` method. I suggest you create a message helper and detect the status in the `URI` and show the message.

Example:

http://myhoe.com/save/succes

if you see `succes` in your URI the show the message.

Another suggestion is use `AJAX`.

:)